# How to use regexp_substr in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I tried following query. to detect login name as follows.

`select regexp_substr('{id:ABCDE,priority:Similar,logins:[test123]}','logins:\[(.*)\]') as login_name`

My desired result is to get `test123`.
But when I execute this query, it returned nothing.

What is the wrong point of that ?
If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "Redshift Postgres". It's either Redshift or Postgres. Those are two very different database systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace` function and get capture group with `\:numberGroup`

```sql
select regexp_replace(
  '{id:ABCDE,priority:Similar,logins:[test123]}',
  '.*logins:\s*\[(.*)\].*', 
  '\1'
) as login_name
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I understood that letters matches this condition will be returned . can I extract letters only in `test123` ? thanks